# Adding two numbers in two string variables in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have two numbers in variables, i need to add those two variable and the result needs to go into another variable. But all three variable need to be strings in the end because im using them for the value of `content:`

You can see my CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/marcchoover/pen/BKQErP).

There you can see that `$minority` and `$majority` works, as i already have them set as strings, but when i try to add them together for the variable `$btctotal`, it just concatenation them. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just made my original two numbers as integers, and then when it was time to display next to `content:` i just used interpolation `#{ }`

http://codepen.io/marcchoover/pen/BKQezE